# iOS Crashlytics in Firebase not working in Swift 4.1

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, swift4.1, xcode9.4

First We have integrated Firebase analytics and its working fine. We are able to see the custom events on the dashboard

But when we integrate crashlytics crash reports are not displaying on a dashboard. Following are the steps which I followed:

1. Registered The App.
2. Downloaded Config file plist and added it to the project.
3. Added the Firebase SDK through cocoa pods.

4.Added initialization code.

In `AppDelegate` class in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions()` added following code,

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

All events were generated as per expectation. But when I integrate Crashlytics in Firebase Analytics, it shows **crash reports submitted successfully** but crash reports are not reflected on the dashboard. We have also changed the project scheme to release mode but no success.

I have even set the build settings to dwarf with dSYM file. Added the script "{PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" but nothing is working.

Can anyone help us to look into this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. We had a production issue on Wednesday into Thursday that may have affected your app. Try submitting a new crash.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Same problem with my iOS app. I am working on xcode 10.2 using pods as 
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.2'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.14.0'

It is generating crash but not logging in Firestore. Other analytical events are triggering.

Comment: I'd recommend reaching out to support if you're encountering difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

Which version (xcode and crashlytics) are you using? A couple days ago I was developing a new version and simultaneously trying both uploading **manually** and using the **run script** - none of them were working - so I've checked for updates [here](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/update) and as you can see:

> **3.10.9 October 4, 2018**
>
> Improves automatic dSYM uploading for Fabric Mac App users.
>
> **3.10.8 September 27, 2018**
>
> Fixed a bug preventing Xcode 10 users from uploading dSYMs in some cases.

They're directly related to the upload/use of dSYMs. That's just a hunch, but may be related in some way to your issue.